# How to check list of elements present in nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
l = ["a","b"]
d = {
    "val1": { "a": {"a1": "vfvf", "a2": "ghbnnhn"},
              "b": {"b1": "gghh", "b2": "nhghbfb"},
              "c": {"c1": "fgggfgf ","c2 ":"hhggbfvfv"}
            },
    "val2": { "d": {"d1": "vfvf", "d2": "ghbnnhn"},
              "e": {"e1": "gghh", "e2": "nhghbfb"},
              "a": {"a_1": "fgggfgf ","a_2 ":"hhggbfvfv"}
            }
}
```

Have to check `list 'l'` and `print dictionary elements of corresponding list element`.

**Code**

```
for k,v in d.items():
    if "a" in v:
        print(d[k][a])
    if "b" in v:
        print(d[k][b])
```

I think, above approach is tedious and time consuming. Can it be `optimised` instead of `two if loops` like below ?

```
for k,v in d.items():
      if any(l) in v:
         print(d[k][whichever_element_matches_above])
```

Or any other better approach than this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a double-comprehension:

```
to_print = [
    v2 
    for k,v in d.items()
    for k2,v2 in v.items()
    if k2 in l
]
print(to_print)
# [{'a1': 'vfvf', 'a2': 'ghbnnhn'}, {'b1': 'gghh', 'b2': 'nhghbfb'}, {'a_1': 'fgggfgf ', 'a_2 ': 'hhggbfvfv'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only one for loop, you can use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) package.
Example:

```
import itertools

l = ["a","b"]
d = {
    "val1": { "a": {"a1": "vfvf", "a2": "ghbnnhn"},
              "b": {"b1": "gghh", "b2": "nhghbfb"},
              "c": {"c1": "fgggfgf ","c2 ":"hhggbfvfv"}
            },
    "val2": { "d": {"d1": "vfvf", "d2": "ghbnnhn"},
              "e": {"e1": "gghh", "e2": "nhghbfb"},
              "a": {"a_1": "fgggfgf ","a_2 ":"hhggbfvfv"}
            }
}

    
keys_list = list(d.keys())
values_list = list(d.values())

for i, j in itertools.product(l,d.values()):
        if i in j:
            print(keys_list[values_list.index(j)],':', i, ':', j[i])
```

OR

You can use below code with two for loops:

```
for i in l:
    for j in d.values():
        if i in j:
            print(i, ':', j[i])
```

Comment: Any possibilities with single for loop ?

Comment: You can use itertools, I have added a sample code with itertools in my comment

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to include "val1" and "val2" in output respectively ?

Comment: I mean, we are missing to print keys 'val1' & 'val2'.

Comment: Sure, I have updated my code to print dictionary d's keys as well